# displaying image onclick working fine, but how do I hide it on click again

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this HTML and JavaScript code that pops up an image on click of a button, and it is working perfectly fine. however when the image pops up.. I cannot close it back wherever I click in the page. Is there a javascript function that would allow you to un-display it on click again

here is my code

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
function openImage(){
    document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.visibility="visible";
}
</script>
```

```css
#button {
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: Transparent;
  border: solid #ffffff 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="button" onClick="openImage();">Get Started</button>
<img id="loadingImage" src="PNG/Module.png" style="visibility:hidden"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function openImage(){
if ( document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.visibility == "visible" ) {
    document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.visibility="hidden";
} else {
   document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.visibility="visible";
}
```

(For the sake of clarity and debugging, you might want to change the function name from openImage() to toggleImage() )

Comment: Yes now it is working. so is this function usually called toggle ?

Comment: Yes, if you're switching the state of something from its current state to its alternate state, regardless of what the state is, then that's normally referred to as toggling.

Comment: you call it toggle because it alternates the image style from hidden to visible every time you click the button.

Comment: I will in 3 minutes !